# NameError: undefined local variable or method `bitly' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I could not find a solution to this problem for days. I am a ruby on rails beginner, so I am sure I am missing something obvious.

I am trying to shorten the URL of by website to link to it in a tweet that I want to create for each new event. When I create a new event on my site I get the following error:

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `bitly' for main:Object
>       from (irb):7
>       from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in`start'
>       from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
>       from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in`'
>       from script/rails:6:in `require'
>       from script/rails:6:in`'

I am using the [bitly gem](https://github.com/philnash/bitly).

In my gemfile, I have:

```
gem 'bitly', "~> 0.9.0"
```

I have created a bitly.rb file in config/initializers:

```
Bitly.configure do |config|
  config.api_version = 3
  config.login = "xxxx"
  config.api_key = "yyyy"
end
```

In my event model, I have:

```
after_create :tweet_event

def tweet_event
    client = Bitly.client
    u = bitly.shorten('http://www.weinevents.de')
    u = u.short_url
    tweet = title + " " + u
    send_tweet(tweet)
end
```

In my application_helper.rb file, I have:

```
def send_tweet(tweet)
    client = Twitter::Client.new
    client.update(tweet)   
end
```

And in my application_controller I have

```
require 'bitly'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typo. You have `bitly.shorten('http://www.weinevents.de')`. When the documentation says `bitly.shorten`, `bitly` refers to a client object, which you have named `client`. Hence:

```
client.shorten('http://www.weinevents.de')
```